# Refund event with click

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

```
    var divpro = document.getElementsByClassName("userPage__orderList")
    
      for(let i = 0; i<divpro.length; i++){
    var div1 = divpro[i];
    var refundButtons = div1.querySelectorAll(".btn.returnAction");
refundButtons.forEach((refundButton) => {
  refundButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    var urun = div1.getElementsByClassName('userPage__orderListItem--title mb-2')[0].innerHTML


    var fiyat = div1.querySelector(".userPage__orderListItem--price").innerHTML
    dataLayer.push({
      event: "refund",
      product: urun,
      price: fiyat
    });
  });
});
```

};

ı want to create refund event. there are a few problem with it

so there are a few div and each div has products info like name, price vs and each div has refund button (buton tex "refund your order") customer may have 2 order they might me just refund one of them. so ı want to create the event for these condition . [general imagi for "my orders page"as you can see customer my my have a few order and they might want to refund only one of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liSSX.png) every refund button has a same calass name ("btn returnAction") and evey div has same class name("userPage__orderList" refund button in these div)
if you help me at the end gonna create event with google tag manager

[thats the image of one of order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzwk4.png)

[thats my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E66Qk.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sorry abouth that ı am new at this website and ı can not see "edit my questions" button anywhere . where can ı find it